# Custom filter is not working - Magento

Tags: magento

I've made a custom filter 'gender' through admin panel. Unfortunately it is not showing on front like the price filter. The price filter on my site is working fine.

Comment: you should provide more information... if I just tell you that I created a new Shopping Cart Rule and that my old one is working ... are you able to help me ??

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

one guess: if it were an attribute in an attribute set, did you define the attribute as `use in layered navigation` ?

M